# filter sql rows using update statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which can get invalid refby(is related to id), please check following db structure...

```
| id | acnumber  | refby |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | ac01      | 2      |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  2 | ac02      | 1      |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  3 | ac03      | 5      |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

As you can find there is no id with value of 5 in above table so query must return 3rd row as result.

I have tried...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl.members WHERE refby != (SELECT id FROM tbl.members WHERE id = refby)
```

But this is not giving correct results, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE refby not in  (SELECT id FROM members)
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [`not in`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php):-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl.members WHERE refby not in  (SELECT id FROM members)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a LEFT JOIN, NOT IN is slow on large tables... assuming id and refid is an PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE key (read unique within your dataset) then this query should return the same results.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 members members1 
LEFT JOIN
 members members2
ON members1.id = members2.refby 
WHERE members2.id IS NULL
```

check the sqlfriddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05731/1